# Statistical significance test for average revenue

Tags: normal-distribution, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a dataset with a control group and a group who received a phone call. This is a subscription business, so the aim is to see if the average value of their subscription order increased. The average value of their orders before and after the phone call is recorded, e.g. person A might have had an average order of £12 before and £20 after.

First, I am not sure whether it's possible to draw conclusions from this because any tests I do will be on the distribution of means, and I'm not convinced the mean will be a good representation of the average value of their orders. My worry is if they made one larger order then reverted to previous order value it would increase the mean but not necessarily the median/revenue long term. Is this a valid concern or irrelevant in terms of statistical tests and interpreting their outcomes?

If I ignore this and try to determine statistical significance anyway, I've been reading some things that say a t-test for this data would be fine as it would converge to normality with larger sample size (it's absolutely not normal currently!). Then I have some contradicting that and saying non parametric methods should be used. Non parametric seems safer, but would a mann-whitney or wilcoxon test be appropriate? (independent, non-normal continuous data were the criteria for these as far as I understand)

Comment: Why do you think that "any tests I do will be on the distribution of means?"  Many are not. Indeed, Mann Whitney and Wilcoxon, which you mention, are not.